# data is not coming outside the function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to bring the pushed array data outside the function,Every thing is 
    working fine in click function.But when Im trying to print this outside of 
    the function `console.log(this.state.selectedSchedule[0].storeName)` , It is 
    throwing the error:

> Cannot read property 'storeName' of undefined.

Code:

```
this.state = {
    selectedSchedule:[]
};

click(e){
    console.log('e',e);
    document.getElementById("detailView").style.display="block";
    this.state.selectedSchedule=[];
    for(let i=0;i<this.scheduless.length;i++){
        if(this.scheduless[i].scheduleId === e){
            this.state.selectedSchedule.push(this.scheduless[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log('cheudkl',this.state.selectedSchedule);
    this.setState=({
        selectedSchedule:this.state.selectedSchedule
    });
    console.log(this.state.selectedSchedule[0]);
    console.log(this.state.selectedSchedule[0].storeName) //printing
};

//html render
render(){
    console.log(this.state.selectedSchedule[0].storeName) // here it's throwing me the error(not printing)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, initial value of `this.state.selectedSchedule` is `[]` and during initial rendering you are trying to get the `storeName` of 0th items, and clear at that time 0th time doesn't exist so

`this.state.selectedSchedule[0]  ===>`  **undefined**

And you are trying to get the value from `undefined` that's why it is throwing the error. Simply put the check on length before printing the values.

Like this:

```
render(){

    // now it will print the values once some item will be added 
    if(this.state.selectedSchedule.length)
       console.log(this.state.selectedSchedule[0].storeName);

    return (....)
}
```

Another issue is in the way you are updating the state value.

**Changes:**

1- Never mutate the **[state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state)** value directly, Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.

2- **[setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)** is a function so we need to call it `this.setState({})`.

write it like this:

```
click(e){
    document.getElementById("detailView").style.display="block";

    let arr = [];

    arr = this.scheduless.filter(el => el.scheduleId === e);

    this.setState({
        selectedSchedule: arr
    });
};
```

Comment: Checking the length solved my problem..Thanq soooo much

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way of updating the state

```
this.setState=({
    selectedSchedule:this.state.selectedSchedule
});
```

You need to edit this as :

```
if(this.scheduless[i].scheduleId === e){
    this.setState({selectedSchedule:[...this.state.selectedSchedule, this.scheduless[i]]});
    break;
}
```

You need to set the state only then the render function will be called again and your changes to the state variable will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mutate the state, `push` is mutating the `array`, and you are re assigning the `state` object in the `click` function `this.state = ...`.

Instead, use the builtin `setState` [method of react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to update it:

```
this.setState({key: value});
```

As for arrays you can add items with the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) without mutating it:

```
const nextState = [...this.state.selectedSchedule, newValue];
this.setState({selectedSchedule: nextState });
```

**EDIT**
As Mayank Shukla mentioned, in addition to this solution you should check to see if the length of your array is bigger then 0:

```
this.state.selectedSchedule.length > 0 && console.log(this.state.selectedSchedule[0].storeName);
```

In the first `render` call this array is empty hence its length is 0.

Comment: Actually, the obvious fix would be using `filter` to create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You should never mutate the state (changing the contents of `this.state`) directly.

That is, instead of assigning an empty array to part of the state and then `push` every item, create a new array:

```
const selectedSchedule = this.scheduless.filter(schedule => schedule.scheduleId === e)
this.setState({selectedSchedule});
```